# How to highlight and enable only specific weekdays in Tempus Dominus Bootstrap-4 datetime picker?

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using [Tempus Dominus Bootstrap-4 datetime picker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/) 
I am initializing it like this:-

```
$("div[id*='BookingDate']").datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        format: 'L',
        allowMultidate: true,
        viewDate: moment('2019-08-10', 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        minDate:new Date('2019-06-20'),
        maxDate:new Date('2024-06-20'),
});
```

I need to enable particular weekdays and highlight them. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you find solution to this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

To enable only certain weekdays, you can use the [`daysOfWeekDisabled`](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#daysofweekdisabled) option to disable any weekdays that you don't want enabled, and thus enable the ones you don't include in your list. For instance, to disable weekends, add `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]` to your `datetimepicker` options:

```js
 $(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        format: 'L',
        allowMultidate: true,
        viewDate: moment('2019-08-10', 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        minDate:new Date('2019-06-20'),
        maxDate:new Date('2024-06-20'),
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
   });
 });
```

As for highlighting the enabled days, you can apply a custom CSS rule to change the `background-color` on the day elements that are not disabled and not active like so:

```css
#datetimepicker1 > div > ul > li.show > div > div.datepicker-days > table > tbody > tr > td:not(.disabled):not(.active) {
    background-color: #7abaff;
}
```

This assumes that your HTML has a certain structure, but you can mess around in the Chrome inspector and copy the CSS selector for the day elements to make it work in your setup.

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/760cuhp4/) as a demo that shows how this looks. Hope this helps!